# Make footer stick to the bottom only when the page is small enough

Tags: html, css

I have a specific situation regarding how a footer should behave.

In the case where the browser window is big enough, the website will look something like this:

[image]

Notice that there's some white space under the footer: this is what I want, so this case is fine.

However, when I resize the browser window this is what happens obviously:

[image]

This is not what I want. What I want is the footer to stick at the bottom from the moment the window is too small to fit all the content.

The yellow "Content" part should shrink, but the header and footer should keep the same size, and the footer should stick to the bottom.

I am not sure how to process. I think I could maybe use media queries so if the window size is less than Header+Content+Footer base height, then I could change the CSS of the footer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example of how to achieve this behavior using javascript.

```js
var header = document.querySelector('.header');
var content = document.querySelector('.content');
var footer = document.querySelector('.footer');

var resizeHandler = function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('no-scroll', innerHeight > document.body.offsetHeight);
};

resizeHandler();
addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.footer {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}

body.no-scroll {
  height: 99.9vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header"
                       "content"  
                       "footer"
}

body.no-scroll .header {
  grid-area: "header";
}
body.no-scroll .content {
  grid-area: "content";
}
body.no-scroll .footer {
  grid-area: "footer";
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Title</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout and behavior you desire is trivially achievable using the [CSS Flexible Box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox).

```
<body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <section>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ornare est sit amet mauris venenatis, sit amet aliquet justo faucibus. Donec fringilla leo lacinia odio sollicitudin, id posuere justo feugiat. Nunc iaculis, justo ac placerat suscipit, nunc eros blandit justo, ut mattis libero felis vitae diam. Curabitur odio velit, porttitor bibendum sem sit amet, euismod commodo urna. Phasellus finibus fermentum purus at pellentesque. Ut ut felis et eros aliquam mattis. Vivamus quis consequat diam.</p>
        <p>Donec euismod tellus ex, eget venenatis est iaculis scelerisque. Fusce magna nunc, venenatis nec leo non, posuere tincidunt urna. Donec vel lacus sed eros dignissim pellentesque quis et purus. Donec in mauris mi. Praesent eget malesuada ante, a euismod nulla. Suspendisse tincidunt bibendum magna, accumsan mollis urna consequat varius. Curabitur sed ex magna. Quisque vestibulum purus nec leo rutrum accumsan.</p>
        <p>Pellentesque hendrerit consectetur leo, non maximus metus vehicula non. Donec faucibus lectus pretium vestibulum facilisis. Donec rhoncus ante vitae elit viverra commodo. Donec eu ornare sapien. Ut ut elit nulla. Phasellus at tortor a nulla malesuada bibendum. Phasellus non orci porta, porttitor magna in, dapibus magna. Mauris sed tellus sit amet augue rutrum vestibulum. Curabitur lobortis, magna vel maximus bibendum, mi nunc volutpat massa, eu pretium elit lorem id urna. Phasellus ullamcorper finibus quam, a venenatis felis hendrerit sit amet. Proin imperdiet, metus id dictum pretium, elit nisi ornare nisi, finibus condimentum libero velit ut sapien. Aenean in dui efficitur, laoreet neque eu, dictum mi. Curabitur eleifend mauris augue, eget placerat quam hendrerit a.</p>
    </section>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

And the CSS rules:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
}

body > section {
    overflow: auto;
}
```